# Find and compare sequential divs using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having difficulty trying to figure this out and I am hoping some can lead me in the right direction.

I have 20 white divs, separated from chart 1 and chart 2 when a person clicks on a div on chart 1 I have a simple Jquery that changes the the hidden input value to black. When a person clicks on a div on chart 2 the jquery changes the hidden input value to selected.

The problem I am trying to solve is when four or more inputs are black I would like to know if there are 4 sequential inputs in a row that are black.

Ex. chart1div3, chart1div4, chart1div5, chart1div6, chart1div9.

In this example chart 1 divs 3, 4, 5, 6 are sequential now I would like to know if any of the selected divs in chart 2 are equal to any one of the sequential divs in chart 1, such as chart2div4.

Now for the final hurdle, I need to ignore divs 1, 10, 11, 20.

I can not figure out how to go about this, I can return true if there are four or more on chart 1, I can not figure out how to check to see if there is an input on chart 2 equivalent to one in chart 2.

I have been back and fourth and I feel like my code is just not gonna get there. If anyone can show me a solution to my problem I would really appreciate it.

HTML:

```
<div id="chart1top" class="top">
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div1" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div2" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div3" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div4" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div5" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div6" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div7" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div8" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div9" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div10" class="color" value="white" /></div>
</div>
<div id="chart1bottom" class="bottom">
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div20" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div19" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div18" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div17" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div16" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div15" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div14" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div13" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div12" class="color" value="white" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart1div11" class="color" value="white" /></div>
</div>
<div id="chart2top" class="top">
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div1" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div2" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div3" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div4" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div5" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div6" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div7" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div8" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div9" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div10" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
</div>
<div id="chart2bottom" class="bottom">
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div20" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div19" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div18" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div17" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div16" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div15" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div14" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div13" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div12" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="chart2div11" class="pic" value="unselected" /></div>
</div>
```

CODE:

```
// Get all the inputs
var x = 1;
c1div = {};
c2div = {};
while (x < 20){
    c1div[x] = $('#chart1div'+z).val();
    c2div[x] = $('#chart2div'+z).val();     
        }
    }
    z++;
}


var divarray = [];

for(var w in c1div){
    if(c1div[w] == 'black'){
        divarray.push(w);

    }

}

    var hipcount = 1;
    var looparray = [];

    for (var i=0; i < divarray.length; i++) {


    if(divarray[i] - divarray[i-1] == 1) {  
        hipcount++;
        if(hipcount >= 4){
            console.log('return true:'+ hipcount);
        }
    } else {
        hipcount = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didnt understand your Long  question.Explain properly please.

Comment: give them a datavalues like data-num="1" to data-num="10", then whenever a div is clicked you can increment/decrement that value to check and count in both directions. `$('div[data-num='+i+']')` would be your selector then.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear... This might help you...

first click on Area chart1 and then click area chart 2

`[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/fazalrasel/VJV4a/`